# Updating other objects in cloud code from same table parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

What I try to accomplish:

- User can save locations to a table and put them on active/non active.

Table Location:

- user (pointer to user)
- location (geodata)
- active (bool)

Scenario's:

- User saves a new location it automaticly sets that location to
  active. The others should all be set to non-active.
- User sets a saved location to active, automaticly all other locations
  should be set to non-active.

So in the end in the location table, a user can have many locations but only 1 can be active at the same time.
I thought this is the perfect thing for cloudcode

I put this in cloudcode as beforeSave:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Location", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Location");
    query.equalTo("user", request.object.get("user"));
    query.equalTo("active", true);
    query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      //get all objects in the table and set the active property to false
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            var object = results[i];
             object.set('active',false);
             object.save();
      }
      response.success();
    },
    error: function(error) {
      response.error(error.message);
    }
  });
}
});
```

Guess what happens... All objects are set to false and i think i know why...because when you save an object in cloudcode it will call the parse cloud before save hook again right ?

Is there something i can do about this or is my logic just wrong ?

Comment: @cricket_007 typo :)

Comment: Alright, so this doesn't work? Are you sending an Active location? If not, you could set a timestamp and use an after save function to set the most recent location to active

Comment: @cricket_007 hmm i dont really understand what you are saying.. because you will still be in a loop right

Comment: Why do you need the loop if you should only have one active location at a time?

Comment: @cricket_007 i dont need the loop but I think the logic you are saying will still stay in a loop

Comment: I don't think so. You set all locations to not active. You save one active location and the time the location was inserted into the database. Then, the after save trigger sets that one location to active. No loops

Comment: if you have only one active location you don't need to query all you can replace find() with first() because you know you have only one active location

Comment: I thought let me use the updatedAt in the afterSave but it doesnt work. This beforeSave is flawed by design i have to find another way. Its kind of stupid that a beforesave can be triggerd if you update something in the beforesave again.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this solution :

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Location", function(request, response) {

   var location = request.object;
   if (location.get("active")){
        var query = new Parse.Query("Location");
        query.equalTo("user", request.object.get("user"));
        query.equalTo("active", true);

        query.first().then(function(result){
                results.set('active',false);
               results.save()
            .then(function(){
                response.success();
            });
         },function (error) {
            response.error(error.message);
         });
   } else {
        response.success();
   }
});
```

So when you save an "inActive" location the beforeSave response is OK. If you save a new Active Location, it will first check the only active locaton (query.first) and set it to inactive (by this way it's beforeSave will succed) and then you save your new active location.